# Missing NSCameraUsageDescription key even though it is embedded in the binary

Tags: xcode, privacy, info.plist

Attempting to debug OBS Studio in Xcode 11.1 (11A1027) under macOS Catalina 10.15 (19A583), and I've hit a really weird bug(?).

Following [Apple's instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html), I have enabled the option to embed a provided `Info.plist` in the binary in my current target:

[image: The required option is enabled]

And I've provided a path to my `Info.plist` further down:

[image: info.plist path]

And indeed, after inspecting the final binary, the `__text` section appears in there:

[image: otool shows the section required]

Further inspection shows that the contents appear to be valid as well:

[image: Contents of the info.plist section in binary]

Despite this, however, macOS crashes my app due to an access violation. Missing `NSCameraUsageDescription` key, apparently:

```
2019-10-17 01:06:23.890247+0300 obs[44536:561479] [access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
```

I have completely ran out of ideas as to why this is not working. Any macOS wizards care to shed some light on this?

Comment: This is on topic here and on stack overflow. Please comment or flag this vkoskiv if you would prefer us to move it to the other site. Please don’t cross post, we can move it if desired.

Comment: Yeah I'd like it to be moved to Stack Overflow if possible.